# What is a transitive Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies, transitive-dependency

This question is about to clarify what exactly a *transitive dependency* is and how it works at very high level in Maven.

My definition: in a dependency tree like *A --> B --> C*, **C is a transitive dependency for A**. Assume *B* has scope *compile* within *A*.

If *C* has scope *compile* within *B*, then declaring *B* as dependency of *A* suffices to build *A* with Maven. But if *C* has scope *provided* within *B* then, when Maven builds *A*, the building will not automatically compile *A* against *C* unless *A* declares *C* among its dependencies.

Is this correct?

Comment: What does against mean in 'compile A against C'? I'm a mvn beginner and I noticed this example is exactly what I didn't know. I'm thinking A against C as 'using some `import C.someClass` at A.someClass'. Is this correct?

Comment: @GabrielRado I guess what he means is if C has scope _provided_ within B, then the artifact generated will not include C. This statement _import C.someClass at A.someClass_ will work when you have C in your classpath at compile time but if for some reason is NOT provided at runtime, you'll get no class def found exception.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

There are two types of Maven dependencies:

- **Direct:** These are dependencies defined in your `pom.xml` file under the `<dependencies/>` section.
- **Transitive:** These are dependencies that are dependencies of your direct dependencies.

Dependencies with `provided` scope are meant to:

- Either be excluded from the final artifact (for example, for `war` files you would not want to include `servlet-api`, `servlet-jsp`, etc)
- Or overriden -- where the project that inherits these defines a version and/or overrides the scope

Comment: What if C can't be resolved? How would I know B->C so I can change B's version? I checked parent pom and effective pom it's not there.

Comment: If an artifact's POM file cannot be resolved from the remote repository, Maven will throw an error while trying to build the dependency tree.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, if we added `JUnit` as a dependency in `pom.xml` under `<dependencies>` tag. It will download the other `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` file and it is under ***Maven Dependencies***, This `.jar` file can be called **`Transitive dependency`**.

[image]

Resource:- https://youtu.be/ypVE8EgDzzI

Answer (score -9):

A dependency that should be included when declaring project
itself is a dependency